# how to change the state of a tab2 from tab1 (not rebuild tab2) in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

i have a problem when i try to change state of tab2 from tab1

for this, I already have clases of tab1 and tab2 to keep user data with:

```
AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<...>{...}
...
@override
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

the problem is when the user change an option in tab1 y need to change only
state of tab2 (not rebuild) for update only a list var with new data

I have created a tabcontroller so that tab2 changes its state when the user accesses that view but it doesn't work

```
    class _medState extends State<HomeMed> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
    
      TabController _tabController;
      var _context;
      
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    
        _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
      }
    
      void _handleTabSelection() {
        if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
          switch (_tabController.index) {
            case 1: //tab2
              setState(() {
                        });  //this not update tab2 view
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _tabController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` call in `HomeMed` page is supposed to rebuild the whole widget, so both `Tab1` and `Tab2` will rebuild. If you have only a section of Tab2 that would like to rebuild, better you use `ValueNotifier` or a `Service`